# mongodb query third level with unknown property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to perform a query in mongodb. The documents are stored as follows

```
    {
        "_id": "5b506440a7769100817265b2",
        "zones": [
            "London",
            "Berlin",
            "Rome"
        ],
        "width": 100,
        "price_list_id": 2,
        "heights": {
            "200": {
                "window_fixed_arch_low": {
                    "default": false,
                    "price": "2"
                }
            },
            "300":{
                "window_fixed_arch_regular": {
                    "default": false,
                    "price": "3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I just want to retrieve all the documents having `heights.*.window_fixed_arch_regular` property. I tried with

```
({'heights.$.window_fixed_arch_regular', 'exists', true})
```

but with no luck.

What is the query that "searches" in all the heights (in my case 200 & 300) without specify it and checks if "window_fixed_arch_low" exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query in 3.6.

[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert the `heights` document into key value pairs followed by [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to compare the input value against values in a document.

[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) accepts aggregation expression in find queries.

[`$gt > null`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) - aggregation expression to check where the matching value exists followed by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to output the count.

[`$gt > 0`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) - aggregation expression to check where count is greater than 0.

```
db.collectionName.find({
  "$expr":{
    "$gt":[
      {"$size":{
        "$filter":{
          "input":{"$objectToArray":"$heights"},
          "cond":{"$gt":["$$this.v.window_fixed_arch_low",null]}
        }
      }},
      0
    ]
  }
})
```